# Rest API call to Salesforce from site - one call only

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, authorization

I created a Rest service to insert/update contacts & opportunities from a donation page on my client's site. The web developer refuses to make more than one call from the script that posts to my REST class.

Both OAuth & Username/Password authentication require 2 calls (potentially) OAuth - once I've got the initial refresh token, it requires a new token every time the old token expires, & Username/Password requires a new token on each call. I really don't want to use the Username/Password flow in any case as it is insecure.

Does anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's going to be at least two calls involved unless you use webhook-style authentication on a Apex REST API endpoint exposed to the public through a Force.com Site. With that style of authentication, you accept input from *any* caller in an unauthenticated session, and authenticate it through an HMAC with a pre-shared secret key. The running user for your Apex is the site guest user, rather than some integration or system user.

You lose some control here. You don't have a Connected App. You can't track inbound logins that way. Anybody on the Internet can poke your API - you have to code very, very defensively. I'm not an infosec expert but there's definitely implications to think through (how about a replay attack, for example?)

No matter which OAuth flow you use, or even if you decided to use a SOAP `login()` call to get a Session Id, you'll have *at some point* to make a call to obtain a the session id (one call), plus making the actual call to your REST endpoint (two calls).

Personally, I would treat this more as a communication problem than a technical one. The web developer's intransigence doesn't really make sense to me on the face of it, and is going to push you to use a less-optimal architecture for, potentially, no good reason. I'd talk it through and find out why.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I agree about the web developer :)